# How to edit dynacmically added buttons from class other then main activity

Tags: java, android

I am learning to program in android to transfer my java application to my phone but I am running into a very basic problem I can't find the answer for.
I am dynamically adding buttons and changing there color when I press them. This works fine when I do it in main activity but when I try to clean up my code by making seperate classes it breaks.
Code is provided below.
This is my first question here so I might have messed up the formating sorry in advance.

Main activity

```
 public void test(View view) {
    View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.newwindow, null);
    ViewGroup insertPoint = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.testlayout8);
    insertPoint.addView(v, 0, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
}

public void multbut(View view) {
    view.setBackgroundColor(11111);
}
```

New Java class extends Main activity

```
public void multbut2(View view) {
    view.setBackgroundColor(11111);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not pass views to another classes other than `MainActivity`.
Java is using "Pass by value" for non-primitive objects but you should do your changes on the same reference of the view that you added to the container(screen).

when you pass the views, java will make a copy from them in the new class and that's cause of your problem

Comment: Thanks so it's passing views that's the problem. I will keep those functions in MainActivity then. Do you have any advice on keeping that class small? It will probably become quite large since I can't pass views to other classes.

Comment: @queza you should follow MVVM or MVP architecture (MVVM recommended by google)
search about it, and I can support you if you had any question about it.